# Continuity of an integral depending on a parameter resembling convolution by mollifiers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am stuck trying to prove/disprove the following:

Let $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(\frac{y-t}{x})f(t)dt$ where $(x,y)\in (0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$.
Here, $\phi\in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$.
The problem asks if $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,y_{0})}g(x,y)$ exist with some fixed $y_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am aware of the standard application of the Dominated Convergence Theorem which would give the continuity of such integrals in $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$. However, I think the issue at $x=0$ means that that wouldn't work.

If $\phi$ were a standard mollifier, I think $\frac{1}{x}\phi(\frac{y-t}{x})$ approaches $\delta(y-t)$ hence the limit of $g$ would be $f(y_{0})$. So I'm looking for counterexamples with less regular $\phi$, but haven't found any yet. I would appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a change of variable $s=t/x$ and see if you can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you @uniquesolution for the hint! I'm sorry but I was hoping if you could check if I correctly understood what you're saying. I tried the suggested substitution and got $g(s,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{s}{t}\phi(s)f(y-t)dt$, where $s\in\mathbb{R}$. While I see that $\phi$ and $f$ are bounded and $t$ does not cause a problem due to compact support of $f$, I fail to find an integrable function that would dominate for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Apologies & thanks again!

Comment: The substitution should result in $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y/x-s)f(sx)\,ds$.

Comment: wow sorry for the dumb question & thanks for your patience.

Comment: It suffices that $\phi \in L^1$ and $f$ is bounded for the result to be true (it $\to A f(y_0),A=\int_R \phi(x)dx$) if it is not then it depends on the regularity of $f$

Comment: Thanks @reuns for the additional input! Sorry to ask if this is obvious to you, but could you explain further how the limit of the integral exactly picks out the value of f at $y_{0}$ ? I see $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\phi(\frac{y_{0}}{x}-s)f(sx)=0$ unless $sx=y_{0}$. Also it seems that the total mass should be preserved by Fubini (&Tonelli) - but is there more to the rigorous argument justifying the dirac-delta-like behavior (or any error in my understanding)? Also, if $\phi\in L^{1}$ what would the dominating function be (or does the result hold by approximation)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and bounded and $\phi $ is $L^1$ and $C = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(u)du$ and $a\in [-A,A]$, as $n\to\infty$
$$|f(a)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty n \phi(n(t-a))f(t)dt| =|\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \phi(u)(f(\frac{u}{n}+a)-f(a))du|$$
$$\le \int_{|u|\ge n^{1/2}} | \phi(u)(f(\frac{u}{n}+a)-f(a))du|+\int_{|u|\le n^{1/2}} | \phi(u)(f(\frac{u}{n}+a)-f(a))du|$$
$$\le \|f\|_\infty \|\phi 1_{|u|>n^{1/2}}\|_{L^1}+\|\phi\|_{L^1} \sup_{|u-v|\le n^{-1/2}, |u|\le 2A} |f(u)-f(v)| $$